# file_get_contents worked 3 hours ago - now doesn't

Tags: php, file-get-contents, http-request

Three hours ago I was working on my site, then I had a nap, and now my `file_get_contents` request isn't working.

```
$Url = sprintf( "http://www.wowhead.com/item=%u?xml", $EntryId );
$Xml = file_get_contents( $Url );
```

Display ID for example could be 30987. The url formed: `http://www.wowhead.com/item=30987?xml`
This works in a browser - but in my site I get: `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`.

I don't really get it - because it worked perfectly just 3 hours ago.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Start by working out what has changed in that 3 hours

Comment: @Anigel, well nothing that I know of - I went to bed and got back up to work on it. If further information is needed I'll gladly posted it - I tried to figure out what the HTTP error was returned, but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: maybe they blocked you for accessing their page to often

Comment: Did you happen to iterate from 0 to 30987+?

Comment: Hi Loz, I'm not sure what you mean by that - There actually is no loop in the function in which I get the website xml - however, I do loop in the calling function: `for ($i = 0; $i < 17; $i++)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way you are reading the HTTP content can be the problem. You are reading it as a file. That does not send proper HTTP headers. Server may refuse to serve the page contents when the request is not formatted properly. Read the contents of the URL using [HTTPRequest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php)

Comment: curl is a much better option

Comment: @LozCherone Hi, I appear to be missing the `HTTPRequest` class - however I tried curl, and curl works. Very odd, do you have any idea why this would would in curl, and not file_get_contents - keeping in mind that it worked 3 hours ago?

Comment: @KevinMallinson As I told already file_get_contents just opens a socket and tries to read. It does not send HTTP request. A HTTP server has all the right to reject any client not talking proper HTTP protocol. curl talks HTTP protocol. Therefore curl works.